# Is it okay to bump questions?

Tags: discussion

Most of my questions are about quantum field theory. They tend to get extremely few views and a handful of positive votes before sinking off the bottom of the active list. My non-QFT questions are pretty well-received, so I'd like to think I'm not asking totally trivial questions, but almost all the time, to get a QFT answer, I need to give the question a bounty. I think I've given out about 10 bounties at this point.

Am I doing something wrong? I feel like this wouldn't be necessary if I could bump the question a few times, but I never see anybody doing this. Is that allowed?

Comment: Writing good questions, advertising in chat, and using bounties are the two good ways to get attention.

Comment: Answered [on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/263383).

Comment: Like so many other minor *faux pas*, it might be overlooked occasionally, but you shouldn't make a habit of it. To be safe, try to add value with your edits.